# Add Active class to LI element in an already existing javascript code with onclick

Tags: javascript

I see bunch of threads asking how to add a class to make a tag active with javascript. But in my case I already have a javascript which generates a playlist in an Ordered List (OL>LI>A) so I am having difficulties implementing it....

```
    //Create a function to load a playlist var
function loadPlaylist(thePlaylist) {
    jwplayer().load(thePlaylist)
}
var playerInstance = jwplayer("container");
playerInstance.setup({
    playlist: playlistOne
}); 

var list = document.getElementById("list");
var html = list.innerHTML;
playerInstance.on('ready',function(){
var playlist = playerInstance.getPlaylist();
for (var index=0;index<playlist.length;index++){
var playindex = index +1;
html += "<li><a href='javascript:playThis("+index+")'><img alt='"+playlist[index].title+"'src='" + playlist[index].image + "'/>"+playlist[index].title+"</a><span>"+playlist[index].description+"</span><div style='clear:both'></div></li>"
list.innerHTML = html;
}
});
function playThis(index) {
playerInstance.playlistItem(index);
}
```

So above generates a playlist, and as you can see, the html += is where the list get its HTML output. So how would I implement a javascript code so whenever I click on the A link, the LI changes to LI.active

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a string like you did above, just query it like any other elem:

```
html += "<li>...</li>"

document.querySelectorAll("li").forEach(li => {
  li.addEventListener("click", e => console.log(e))
})
```

Alternatively, You can create an element like so:

```
let li = document.createElement("li");
```

You can add an event listener like usual

```
li.addEventListener("click", e => console.log(e));
```

You can then add the elem to the dom:

```
document.body.appendChild(li);
```

Comment: Hi Ced, I have tried your first alternativ and placed it right after html += "<li>...</li>"...
But it kills the videoplayer. Nothing is showing.
I feel lost with your other alternatives... sorry

Answer (score 0):

You can use `remove` and `add` on the `classList` property of the element.

```
function playThis(index) {
    var liElems = document.querySelectorAll('ul > li');

    // remove the active class for all the li
    liElems.forEach(function(elem) {
         elem.classList.remove('active');
    });

    // add the active class to the clicked li
    this.parentNode.classList.add('active');


    playerInstance.playlistItem(index);
}
```

Comment: Hi Sushanth. Thanks for your comment. But how and where do I implement this function? I have tried putting it after the playlist script but to no avail....

Comment: First open the dev tools in your browser and check if you see any errors

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
    var listItems = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
    for (var i = 0; i < listItems.length; i++) {
        listItems[i].addEventListener('click',changeClass,false);
    }
}
function changeClass() {
    this.classList.add("active");
}
</script>
<ul>
    <li>song1</li>
    <li>song2</li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Aquaballin, but where should I add that line of javascript code?

Comment: You should be able to add it anywhere. I edited my answer.

Comment: Actually one sec I will edit my answer when I get to my computer, that is not right I do not think.

Comment: Here you go man, this should help you a lot. If it works out for you, can you mark the answer as correct by checking the green check mark? Thanks!